# Scrollbar still is painted after it should be removed

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, scrollbar

I have the following custom control and can place on a form (with AutoScroll set to true and the control anchored left, top and right).

If the form is too short for the control, the form correctly resizes the control (to make room for the scroll) and displays the scroll bar.

When the control is closed using the close glyph, the control is resized and the scroll bar is removed, but occasionally the scroll bar appears to remain painted.  If the form is minimized or moved off-screen, the leftover paint is removed.

I've tried Parent.Invalidate and have toyed with it in many ways but to no avail.  Any suggestions?

(Using VS 2008 Standard)

[alt text http://waltware.homedns.org/screenshot.jpg](http://waltware.homedns.org/screenshot.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace GroupPanelTest
{
    public class GroupPanel : GroupBox
    {
        #region Members
        private const Int32 iHeaderHeight = 20;
        private Int32 iFullHeight = 200;

        private Boolean bClosed = false;
        private Rectangle rectCloseGlyphBounds = Rectangle.Empty;
        private Boolean bIsMoveOverCloseGlyph = false;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public Boolean Closed
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.bClosed);
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.bClosed != value)
                {
                    this.bClosed = value;
                    if (this.bClosed)
                    {
                        this.iFullHeight = base.Height;
                        base.Height = GroupPanel.iHeaderHeight;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        base.Height = this.iFullHeight;
                    }

                    foreach (Control con in base.Controls)
                        con.Visible = !this.bClosed;

                    this.Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        public new Int32 Height
        {
            get
            {
                return (base.Height);
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != base.Height)
                {
                    if (this.Closed)
                    {
                        this.iFullHeight = value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Int32 iOldHeight = base.Height;
                        base.Height = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [DefaultValue(typeof(Size), "350,200")]
        public new Size Size
        {
            get
            {
                return (base.Size);
            }
            set
            {
                if (base.Size != value)
                {
                    base.Size = value;
                    if (!this.Closed)
                        this.iFullHeight = value.Height;
                }
            }
        }

        [DefaultValue(typeof(Padding), "0,7,0,0")]
        public new Padding Padding
        {
            get
            {
                return (base.Padding);
            }
            set
            {
                base.Padding = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Construction
        public GroupPanel ()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);

            this.Size = new Size(350, 200);
            this.Padding = new Padding(0, 7, 0, 0); // the groupbox will add to that
            this.rectCloseGlyphBounds = new Rectangle(base.ClientSize.Width - 24, 2, 16, 16);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Overrides
        protected override void OnSizeChanged (EventArgs e)
        {
            this.rectCloseGlyphBounds = new Rectangle(base.ClientSize.Width - 24, 2, 16, 16);
            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e); // we want all the delegates to receive the events, but we do this first so we can paint over it

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            g.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, this.ClientRectangle);
            Rectangle rectTitle = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, GroupPanel.iHeaderHeight);
            g.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, rectTitle);
            g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, new PointF(5.0f, 3.0f));

            if (this.bIsMoveOverCloseGlyph)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.ButtonHighlight, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds);
                Rectangle rectBorder = this.rectCloseGlyphBounds;
                rectBorder.Inflate(-1, -1);
                g.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.Highlight, rectBorder);
            }

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(SystemColors.ControlText, 1.6f))
            {
                if (this.Closed)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(pen, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 3, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 3, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 8);
                    g.DrawLine(pen, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 13, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 3, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 8);

                    g.DrawLine(pen, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 3, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 7, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 12);
                    g.DrawLine(pen, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 13, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 7, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 12);
                }
                else
                {
                    g.DrawLine(pen, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 3, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 3);
                    g.DrawLine(pen, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 13, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 3);

                    g.DrawLine(pen, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 3, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 12, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 7);
                    g.DrawLine(pen, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 13, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 12, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Left + 8, this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Top + 7);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown (MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Contains(e.Location))
                this.Closed = !this.Closed; // close will call invalidate
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove (MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.bIsMoveOverCloseGlyph = this.rectCloseGlyphBounds.Contains(e.Location);
            this.Invalidate(this.rectCloseGlyphBounds);
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Something very strange in your screenshot.  How did the glyph manage to get painted on top of the scrollbar?  Chase that.

Answer (score 0):

You must call Control.Update() after Control.Invalidate() to get the desired effect.  Or make your life slightly easier by simply calling .Refresh().

Comment: Hmm...  That's strange since it goes away when drug off screen.  Every time I've seen that behavior it's been the case that an Invalidation/Update pass fixes it (that's basically what happens when you drag it off screen too).  I'll post back if I figure it out.